# Hack a LAN with low security

Tags: network, wireless

In our university users have to use VPN to connect to internet.But for local works(like login to university website,checking their university accounts) VPN is not needed.And as I know we have unencrypted wireless LAN connection which is not secure at all.
As a computer student, to show these problems I want to get some passwords of users accounts or get some files of on users computers.(without using any hacking software)
As I never have such experience before, I searched a lot but I didn't find a good way.I prefer to use CMD.
What are the best ways to hack such LANS?

Comment: Chances are, getting other users passwords and files without permission is a better way to get expelled and prosecuted than it is a good way advocate for better security.

Comment: What you are trying to do is a good way to get kicked out of school.  It is almost certainly in violation of the terms of use you agreed to when getting access to the school network.  There are better ways to bring problems to their attention than hacking it as a demonstration.  In some jurisdictions, it may even be illegal.  If you are going to do anything, I would suggest compromising your own connection and show them how you were able to detect your own files going across the network.

Comment: It's a project and we have to do it while our professor is staring at us:)
He said we should just SHOW we CAN do that without opening their files or using their passwords.I talked to him about legal issues before but I'm still worry.Thanks everyone.

Comment: @user1181065 - as long as it is an official project, then I'd be less worried, particularly if you limit your sniffing to only a willing participant's system's traffic.  It should be easy enough to apply a mac filter based on their mac address so that you capture only their traffic.  Still might not be a bad idea to contact your school's helpdesk though and make sure they are aware of said project.

Comment: Or get agreement in writing from the network owner/head of IT/dean/?

Comment: Hi, welcome to [security.se]. Please make sure to read the [FAQ] and [ask]. You really need to narrow your question down a bit, be specific. Perhaps do some research before asking, like reading wikipedia or other articles. If you get stuck on a particular problem, you can bring that here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is truly unsecured wireless, then a simple packet sniffer should pick information on the wireless network out of the air though you may have to use special drivers if your wireless card normally only presents information that is being sent to your MAC address.  Most passwords would still be secure though as they should be getting exchanged using secure means such as HTTPS or other handshake protocols.

What you'll get is a raw dump of network traffic though and if you don't know enough to know how to sniff wireless traffic already, you are likely not going to be able to pull much useful out of a raw network traffic dump.  There will be a lot of information there to sift through.

Also, as I mentioned in the comments, what you are trying to do would likely be considered abuse.  I strongly advise not trying it or if you insist on trying it, use two computers and only monitor your own connection on the other computer.  That way you are at least able to make an argument that you were not compromising anyone else, but it's still a really bad idea.

Comment: I second this. Speaking from experience it's a very bad idea to demonstrate without permission. While in good intentions, it's still illegal without express permission.

Comment: Yes I'll do that.Hack myself or my friend who is next to me:)

Comment: thanks AJ Henderson!Would you please give me a more specific answer?I seacrhed about packet sniffing but it seems I have to use software which is not allowed in this project...

Comment: @user1181065 - If you need to write the software yourself, then you would need to write your own packet sniffer.  Such topics are programming related (and fairly deeply so) and not security related though, so it would be off topic here.  You might have better luck asking on StackOverflow for help with writing a packet sniffer.  I would also suggest disclosing that it is looking for assistance on the direction to go with a school project.